# Visual Studio 2015 is reverting to default settings

Tags: visual-studio, settings

Today I have come across a strange problem with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.
I have always set my own editor preferences (colors, fonts etc.) but today VS is resetting it settings back to their default values.
If I load my previously saved settings, it flickers the old settings in the editor, but reverts to its default state straight away!
I have tried devenv.exe" /ResetSettings and then set my own preferences, but it reverts to default no matter what I do.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a file called fontsandcolors.vssettings in the ..\Visual Studio 2015\Settings folder, and that was overriding the CurrentSettings.vssettings values.
After erasing this file (no idea where it came from!), all was well again.

HTH,
Martin.